# Receive base64 image in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to receive base64 image in php from jQuery but I don't know how to access that value inside php?

var tkpfu is Base64 encoded image and I put that var in data but when I try to acces $_POST['tkpfl'] inside PHP it gets an error of undefined variable thpfl.

JavaScript:

```
function __SVTK(){
    var data = {};
    data['tkpfl'] = tkpfu;
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type:           'POST',
        url:            'profil/chatk',
        data:           data,
        cache:          false,
        contentType:    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
        processData:    false
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR,status,errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log(jqXHR.status);
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Console log:

```
Internal Server Error profil:375
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined index:     tkpfl","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/tender\/app\/controllers\/UsersController.php","line":66}}     profil:376
500
```

Comment: `data['tkpfl'] = tkpfu;` so where does that come from?

Comment: var tkp = $.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64();
That is Base64 image just need to parse it to PHP somehow

Comment: So do you mean `data['tkpfl'] = tkp;`?

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake :( data['tkpfl'] = tkp

Comment: var_dump() returns empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution:

```
function __SVTK(){
    $.ajax({
        type:           'POST',
        url:            'profil/chatk',
        data:           {"tkpfl":tkp},
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR,status,errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log(jqXHR.status);
    });
}
```